# Negative to positive number range in regex in bash scripting

Tags: regex, scripting

I am trying to make a regex expression that will validate a number that is in the range of -100 to 100.

I made this regex expression: (^-[1-100]* |^[0-100]*) but it doesn't work as expected.

the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

check(){
input="test1.txt"
while read -r line; do
a=( $line )

for i in "${a[@]:1}"; do
if [[ "$i" =~ (^-[1-100]*|^[0-100]*) ]]; then
echo "$i"
fi
done
done < "$input"
}
check
```

the input file:

```
add $s0 $s1 $s3
sub $s0 $s1
addi $s1 $s2 76
lw $s2 -50($s2)
```

the actual result:
add $s0 $s1 $s3
sub $s0 $s1
addi $s1 $s2 76
lw $s2 -50($s2)

the expected result:
76 -50($s2)